# Is this a valid deductive proof of $2^x \geq x^2$ for all $x \geq 4$?

Tags: proof-writing

I saw a video of somebody saying that you can prove this by saying that $x+1$ will grow by $2$ on the LHS and by $(x+1)^{2}/x^{2}$ on the RHS. But I am not convinced that this is a clean **deductive** proof. Do you agree and if so, how can one make a clean argument? I was thinking about taking the derivative twice and then showing that the ratio blows up, but this way I only show that it's valid as I go to infinity, and not for the finite values.

EDIT: Perhaps I can perform long division and show it that way.

EDIT2: I have already solved this with induction. My intention is to "challenge" the **deductive** proof that I saw in the video.

Comment: There is no $n$ in $2^x \geq x^2$.

Comment: just changed it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematical induction is a form of deductive proof. (It’s unfortunate that its name makes it sound like induction in the sense that is opposed to deduction $-$ coming to a conclusion on the basis of a large number of positive examples and no counterexamples.) 
The argument sketched in the video is essentially the induction step of a proof by induction; it does not pretend to be anything else. It’s informal but correct.

Comment: Once I expand (x+1)^2/x^2 and break up the fraction and cancel common factors: I get for the rate of growth: 2>1+2/x+1/x^2...which is true for integers AND reals above 4.

Comment: A downvote without an explanatory comment is less than helpful $-$ especially when it’s on an answer that is in fact correct.

Answer (score 2):

Take the function $f(x)=2^x-x^2$, we have that $f'(x)=\textrm{ln}(2)\cdot 2^x-2x\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 4$.
Also, noting that $f(4)\geq 0$, we can see that $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 4$, and the result follows.

Comment: Maybe the only problem now is too proof that $\textrm{ln}(2)\cdot 2^x\geq 2x$ for all $x\geq 4$, but this is much more easier.

Comment: ok this looks like a real deductive/direct proof. upvoted

Answer (score 2):

This sort of argument is a special case of inequalities proved by *multiplicative telescopy* - which represents the function $\rm\:f(n)\:$ as a product of its term ratios $\rm\: f(k+1)/f(k),\:$ namely

$$\rm f(0)\  \prod_{k\:=\:0}^{n-1}\, \frac{f(k+1)}{f(k)}\  =  \ \ \color{#C00}{\rlap{--}f(0)}\frac{\color{green}{\rlap{--}f(1)}}{\color{#C00}{\rlap{--}f(0)}}\frac{\color{royalblue}{\rlap{--}f(2)}}{\color{green}{\rlap{--}f(1)}}\frac{\phantom{\rlap{--}f(3)}}{\color{royalblue}{\rlap{--}f(2)}}\, \cdots\,  \frac{\color{brown}{\rlap{--}f(n-1)}}{\phantom{\rlap{--}f(n-2)}}\frac{f(n)}{\color{brown}{\rlap{----}f(n-1)}}\ =\ \ f(n) $$

Therefore if $\rm\:f(0)>g(0)\:$ and if also $\rm\:\dfrac{f(k+1)}{f(k)} > \dfrac{g(k+1)}{g(k)}\:$ then the product of these telescope to

$$\rm f(n)\, =\, f(0)\  \prod_{k\:=\:0}^{n-1}\, \frac{f(k+1)}{f(k)}\ >\ g(0)\  \prod_{k\:=\:0}^{n-1}\, \frac{g(k+1)}{g(k)}\, =\, g(n) $$

[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/161911/242) for a sketch of a telescopic proof of the more general result that exponentials grow faster than polynomials. As I have emphasized here before in [many posts,](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:242+telescopy)  by means of cancelling complicated expressions, *telescopy* often reduces induction problems to trivialities (here if we work with $\rm\,f/g,\,$ the proof reduces to the trivial proof that a product of terms eventually $> 1$ is itself eventually $> 1$).  Difficult problems involving *hyperrational* functions (i.e. $\rm\ f(n+1)/f(n) = $ rational function of $\rm\:n,\:$ e.g. powers, exponentials, factorials) are, after application of telescopy, greatly simplified to trivial problems about *rational* functions - functions so simple that questions about such can be decided mechanically by algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by induction. To start out with, $2^4\ge 4^2$. Next, assume that, for $n\ge 4$, $2^n\ge n^2$. Then
$$2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n\ge 2n^2\ge \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}n^2=(n+1)^2$$
because $(n+1)^2/n^2=(1+1/n)^2\le\frac{25}{16}<2$ for $n\ge 4$.

Comment: the restriction is to avoid induction. i'm only asking w.r.t. to decuctive/direct proof. i have already done the same exercise with induction before, but thx anyway.

Comment: there is no mention of induction in the question

Comment: sorry, i should have made it clearer that im only talking about deductive proofs

Comment: @Wuschelbeutel: Mathematical induction **is** a form of deductive proof. And the argument sketched in the video is essentially the induction step of a proof by induction; it does not pretend to be anything else. It’s informal but correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Ok I just did the expansion and division and it makes sense now.

Comment: @Wuschelbeutel: Thank you; I’ve made an answer out of it.

Answer (score 0):

This proof is not good for the case that $x$ is not a natural number. You can not deduce from the proof that, for example,  $2^{1.5} \geq 1.5^2$

**Added:** the proof you gave also resort to induction IMO since if I ask you why $2^{10} \geq 10^2$ you will tell me about the inequality for $x=9$ - but when I ask you about the inequality for $x=9$ you will have to tell me about the inequality for $x=8$ and so forth untill you reach the base case.

Comment: I claim it's not even good enough for the naturals. But I agree with you on the reals in that case. I assume, one would simply add the fractional part explicitly as a symbol.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - I added some information

Comment: Yes, that's the remark that was also made by Brian M. Scott. However, I fail to see how this proof (from the video) doesn't qualify for reals also. You end up with the expression 1>2/x+1/x^2 (rate of growth comparison between LHS and RHS), which is true for x larger than 4...even non-integers!